# Undefined variable while it is declared

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I m creating a small app that reads data from Firebase and store it in table named "actualiteNews"
it tells me that it is not defined while it is declared

```
import { Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFireDatabase} from 'angularfire2/database';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ActualiteService  {
  actualiteNews : any[];


  constructor(dataBaseFire : AngularFireDatabase) {
    dataBaseFire.list('/news').valueChanges().subscribe(actualiteNews => {
      this.actualiteNews = actualiteNews;
      console.log(this.actualiteNews);
    });

   }

getActualite(Temptitre:string){
    return this.actualiteNews.find(value =>value.titre === Temptitre);
  }

  getActualiteNews(){
    return this.actualiteNews;
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please, consider providing more information and error logs. It will make it easier to people help you. For more information, take a look at [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What variable is it throwing the "undefined" on?

Comment: @maury844 "actualiteNews" variable

Comment: As @How To Ask suggested, maybe you can provide us more information with your errors to see what line may be causing the issue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 actualiteNews : any[] = [];
```

Yes it is declared but you have to set the default value as empty array. You might be doing `actualiteNews.length` in template but you haven't defined `actualiteNews`. That is the reason it is breaking.